# Protect url from decompiling

Tags: android, security, url, hide

I've written an app which connects over PHP to MySQL. The MySQL Passwords are stored in the php file. But i have to save the Url in a String like
    http://www.abc.com/create_user.php
and if someone decompiles the app, he can see the Url and manually create accounts. (I use Post Method in PHP)

Comment: What, precisely, is the question? There's only background or a problem statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' s very difficult to prevent people from seeing what URL **backend** you are using. I would argue that is impossible. If they can't decompile the APP, they still could use a PROXY to inspect traffic from the Android APP to your server.

I would put some stuff to make it more difficult though.

Off the top of my head, you could:

1. Use a CLIENT_SECRET: a compiled string in the Android APP that your server needs to validate in order to make the account creation.
2. Use HTTPs (it will make more difficult to use a PROXY to inspect HTTP traffic)
3. Al alternate way of doing (1) is using CLIENT_SECRET to locally encrypt the payload you are using to create the user
4. Check for a specific USER_AGENT on the HTTP REQUEST

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Can you please more specify "1.", "3." & "4."?

Comment: @user3178507 - its customary to provide an upvote to those who help you if the answer is useful. Its offers the person who answers (and other Stack Overflow visitors) feedback.